# Creating a tbl_continuous with weight data using gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

**Problem:**

Can't find a way to create a `tbl_continuous` of a weighted numerical variable. I'm using `tbl_svysummary` to create my categorical variable tables but it's not useful when i try to do the same with numerical variable tables. Note: i'm not looking for a general mean of my numeric variable but separated by or groupped by a categorical variable.

**Attempt:**

For example, i've created this table with the help of the function `tbl_continuous` which does exactly what i want: the mean of my numeric variable but by the levels of my categorical variable. The only problem is that i can't insert a weight variable into this function.

````
```{r}
base2 %>% 
  as_label() %>% 
  select(ing_cap, ano, nacional, dominio) %>% 
  tbl_continuous(variable = ing_cap, 
                 by = ano,
                 statistic = list(everything() ~ "{median}"))

```
````

[image: table]

Also, i have been creating weighted data with the `srvyr` package in the following way:

```
base2 %>% 
  labelled::drop_unused_value_labels() %>% 
  as_label() %>% 
  as_survey_design(weight = fac500a)
```

Could add up to the solution.

**Request:**

Create this same table (shown in the image) but with a weight variable. My weight variable in my data is called `fac500a`.

**My data:**

My data can be dowloaded from my github repo and has the following dimensions:

```
> dim(base2)
[1] 108103     44
```

https://github.com/aito123/quarto_blog/raw/master/posts/tablas_tesis/base2.sav

(`dput` output is long)

**My current packages:**

I'm using this r packages so far: `tidyverse, srvyr, gtsummary, sjlabelled, haven`

**Conclusion:**

Let me know if it's neccesary to provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gtsummary package does not export an analogous function of `tbl_continuous()` for survey data. But you can construct the table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.6.0'

svy_trial <- survey::svydesign(ids = ~1, data = trial, weights = ~1)

tbl <- 
  svy_trial %>%
  tbl_strata2(
    strata = grade,
    ~ .x %>%
      tbl_svysummary(
        by = trt, 
        include = age, 
        missing = "no",
        label = list(age = .y)
      ) %>%
      modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**"),
    .combine_with = "tbl_stack",
    .combine_args = list(group_header = NULL)
  ) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~ .x %>%
      mutate(variable = "grade", row_type = "level") %>%
      tibble::add_row(
        row_type = "label",
        variable = "grade",
        label = "Grade",
        .before = 1L
      ) 
  ) %>%
  modify_column_indent(columns = label, rows = row_type == "level") %>%
  bold_labels() %>%
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Treatment**") %>%
  modify_footnote(all_stat_cols() ~ "Age: Median (IQR)")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2022-05-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the answer i will apply it to my problem. It would be awesome to implement a tbl_svycontinuous() i believe it would fill the gap for survey data. Regards.

Comment: it's on the list to create a `tbl_custom_svysummary()` (`tbl_custom_summary()` powers the `tbl_continuous()` version). But it's not a priority at the moment, and I have no idea when we'll get to it.